# PHP a href not linking

Tags: php, hyperlink, href

I've been working on managing this site for a little bit and out of nowhere today I've lost functionality of links (of the  type).

I've looked high and low, and I'm pretty sure the syntax is right on this link (it's never given me a problem before), but for some reason it won't link now! I want to pass the 'SomeString' element from my $array[] to myPage.php. Hovering over the link displays the right url, but clicking doesn't do anything. Nor can I right-click on the element in a browser to "Inspect Element", go figure!

```
echo "<li><a href='myPage.php?q=" . $array[$j]['SomeString'] . "'>" . $array[$j]['Name'] . "</a></li>";
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the resulting HTML?

Comment: Use CTRL+U and show us the output.

Comment: CTRL + U doesn't yield anything??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View source and see what it's outputting. I'd bet your `SomeString` has a quotation mark in it - you should be running it through `urlencode`, most likely.

Comment: Nope, no miss-quotes or anything.. I'll do some research on what urlencode can do for me. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcBosse Show us the resulting HTML output that isn't working.

Comment: It just does nothing. No result. When I hover over the link, the url is correct, no quotes, GET variable are correctly set. Click - nothing..

Comment: <ul style="display: block;">
    <li>
        <a href="myPage.php?q=example_data"></a>
    </li>

Comment: @MarcBosse Your link has no text in it. `$array[$j]['Name']` would seem to be missing.

Comment: I'm abstracting the problem, there is a lot more involved in the code. It's something with the browser, it has to be.

Comment: The issue, plain and simple, the <a> tag isn't working. I don't know why yet, works in chrome, if I right-click and open link in a new tab it works just fine, but not just a straight-up link! I've asked coworkers to look it over too and it's as simple as '<a> doesn't want to link'... now to find a cause and cure

Answer (score 0):

Check `$array[$j]['SomeString']` to see if it is returning the same value as before.

```
var_dump($array[$j]['SomeString']);
```

Comment: Returns the value of my array at the specifies index, but won't redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I emptied my cache, the problem went away and the href hyperlinked to my desired page.